# Getting Out of Search Results in Document Library

Tags: document-library, search

We've upgraded our site collection to the "New Look" and now when I'm in a Document Library and I do a search, I can't navigate easily out of the search results. I can click the back button, but if I've searched multiple keywords that's a lot of jumping backwards to get to the root again. I don't understand why I can't just clear the search and go back to the root. I can delete the "&q=" from the URL but I'm not really interested in explaining that to all my users.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a link to the library (or Site Content) in Quicklaunch or top navigation might help. That's how I overcome this. If that's not possible, I'd suggest to jump to the Cog Wheel > Site Content > Library, but that's a lot of clicks as well ;-)